# ANGULAR 5 : translate.get with array of String returns keys and value and not only values

Tags: arrays, json, angular, internationalization

I use angular 5, And part of my code manages the mechanism internationalization  using ngx-translate.

I will explain the scenario of my problem, so I have a data table that retrieves data from a web service and display them perfectly. I have an button to export the data to a csv file using the mechanism of Angular5csv. I have the function below that gives me the header that I have to put above the csv file which depends on the language chosen

```
  getHeader(){
this.translateService.get(['app.lblInvSupNum','app.lblInvTANum',
                           'app.lblDateInv'  ,'app.lblDueDate',
                           'app.lblAmount'  ,'app.lblCurrency',
                           'app.lblStatut'  ,'app.lblBlockCode',                              
                          ])
                      .subscribe((res: any[]) =>{
                        this.header=res; // declaration header: any[];
                        console.log(this.header);

                      })
```

}

When I display the result in the console is as follows

```
{app.lblInvSupNum: "Supplier Invoice Number", app.lblInvTANum: "Invoice Number", app.lblDateInv: "Invoice date", app.lblDueDate: "Due Date", app.lblAmount: "Amount", …}
```

What i am looking for i want an array of String to pass to angular5csv.
Something like that

```
['Supplier Invoice Number','Invoice Number','Invoice Date','Due Date','Amount','Currency','Status','Blockage Code']
```

Thanks you for all.

Comment: You can use `Object.values(data)`, which will return what you want (assuming data is the object above)

Comment: @user184994 I don't find values ​​in object and when I use Object.keys (this.header) the table is filled by the key and not value

Comment: Should be `Object.values` not `Object.keys`

Comment: @user184994 'Values' property does not exist on type' ObjectConstructor
any idea ?

Comment: Okay, I've added an answer below that makes use of `Object.keys` to get the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Object.keys` function along with `.map`, like so:

```
let result = Object.keys(this.headers).map((key) => this.headers[key])
```